# OData service and SQL Server - what data does it read exactly

Tags: sql, sql-server, odata

I'm unable to trace calls to my DB, its posted on Azure, so I got this question - how much work will SQL server actually do?

I have this stored proc that returns a table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prcNew AS
    CREATE TABLE @tblTemp
        Col_1
        Col_2
        Col_3
    .....................
    /* @tblTemp filled something like this */
    INSERT INTO @tblTemp
        SELECT SUM(tblExisting.Col_1)
        SELECT SUM(tblExisting.Col_2)
        SELECT SUM(tblExisting.Col_3)
    .....................
    SELECT * FROM @tblTemp
GO
```

now I have OData website and webservice in IIS, made with Visual Studio 2012, it uses Entity Framework function import to get data from prcNew.

So if I call webservice with 'select' word, trying to get only Col_2 from prcNew:

```
    http://.../MyService.svc/prcNew?$select=Col_2
```

what data exactly will SQL Server pass to the webservice? Will it be only Col_2 indeed? If it wont fetch Col_1 and Col_3 - will it skip calculating those column values inside the procedure too?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will only select one column from the result of the stored procedure. So it will run all the statements in the sp